# Inputing results to inArray from .html (or innerHtml) and making it work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("form").submit(function () {
if ($.inArray($("input:first").val().toUpperCase(), ["UNITED STATES", "USA", "AMERICA"]) > -1) {
//function here
});

<div class="answers">"UNITED STATES", "USA", "AMERICA"</div>

$("form").submit(function () {
if ($.inArray($("input:first").val().toUpperCase(),  [$(".answers").html()]) > -1) {  
//function here
});
```

Within the div with the class answers I have the results I need to validate. When I use jquery function .html the results print out fine, but when it validates it needs to validate the whole sentence : "UNITED STATES", "USA", "AMERICA" not every answer on its own like it does on the first function. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Split to turn your string of answers into an array.
Will probably work better if the answers are not spaced out, e.g. AMERICA,USA not AMERICA, USA

```
$("form").submit(function () {
if ($.inArray($("input:first").val().toUpperCase(), $(".answers").html().split(',')) > -1)
{
    //function here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in what format these answers are. Why do you output them into the HTML instead of into a JS variable?

What could work:

```
var answerarray = $(".answers").text().split(", ");
```

or (I'm not sure about your quotes):

```
var answerarray = jQuery.parseJSON("[" + $(".answers").text() + "]"); // ugliest code I've ever written
```

Comment: I am sure this would work but i used the code below insted seems neater. Thanks.

Comment: Yet, dont forget that Bukkos code does not remove the quotes. Apart from that: You should *not* need to extract these values from HTML.